# Count the ratings of each child element under each parent in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

My Table looks as follows:

[image]

Need to find the number of child elements under the parent with the different ratings like as follows

[image]

For example: Under ELEMENT **'1'** there are three child elements namely **2,3,4** with ratings **C, B, C** respectively. So there are no child(ren) with rating **'A'** but there is **1** element with rating **'B'** & **2** elements with rating **'C'**.

So far, I tried grouping based on parent ID and filtering the ratings but I am not able to build a single query using JOINS.

Comment: that's a pivot query, and mysql doesn't support them. the workarounds get very ugly, very fast. You'd be better off doing the pivoting in client-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT ParentID, 
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Rating = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS A,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Rating = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS B,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN Rating = 'C' THEN 1 END) AS C
FROM mytable
WHERE ParentID IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY ParentID
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/91fb6a/1)

Comment: Awesome !!! I think I can use conditional aggregation in my other queries tooo @Giorgos